# Javascript loading xml, searching, and good practice

Tags: javascript, xml, search-engine

I'm new on this whole web design business, and I am beginning to think I am going against good practices, so I had some questions.

I am making a website for a family company. We have a great deal of products that often change, and I need to make the site in a way that it will be editable by someone else less tech savy when I leave the company. My plan was to keep each product in an xml file loaded via javascript on each page. Later, I might attempt to write another script to make editing these xml files easy.

I am worried about two things. First, I am getting a sense that this is bad practice because some users disable javascript. Second, I am worried that search engines will not be able to find content on my site because all they will see is some template html and some javascript. I would like to be searchable and use good practice, but I have no idea how to solve the issue of dynamically changing content that is easy to edit in another way.

I would really appreciate if someone would point me in the right direction so that I know what I should be researching.

Thanks

RShom

Answer (score 1):

There are many good free, open-source software products that let you create a customizable content management system (CMS).  [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) and [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) are very popular ones.

Try searching for "free cms" and see what you find.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you must have heard of PHP, even if you are not using it. I suggest you use PHP to parse your XML into HTML and present. Then your content will be searchable because PHP is server-side scripting. You are going to be using javascript, too, but it shouldn't be for the XML. It is to me for enhancement of a webpage (aside AJAX).